# XPath selecting parent or child element

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to create a XPath to get the value of the element `LMS/LMS.1/LMS.1.1` but sometime the sub-element `LMS.1.1` does not exist and the text is in the parent element `LMS.1`.

Input Case 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <LMS>
        <LMS.1>
            <LMS.1.1>content1</LMS.1.1>
            <LMS.1.2>shouldNotBeSelected</LMS.1.2>
        </LMS.1>
    </LMS>    
</root>
```

Input Case 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <LMS>
        <LMS.1>content2</LMS.1>
        <LMS.2>shouldNotBeSelected</LMS.2>
    </LMS>    
</root>
```

How should I create the XPath that it is generic and can **handle both cases with one XPath**?

*i.e. `//LMS.1/text()` does return only return content2*

Or the other approach: **Select parent text if given leaf element does not exist**: //LMS.1/LMS1.1 would also return content1.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the text content of an entire subtree by requesting the `string-value` of its topmost node -- presumably the `<LMS.1>` element in this case.. However, that will also include whitespace, which I'm guessing you'll want to strip off.

So: `normalize-space(/root/LMS/LMS.1)` should be close to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This expression

```
//LMS/descendant::*[not(*)]/text()
```

selects the text node of the leaf node of any LMS sub tree

Comment: But this selects all text() elements inside LMS. There can be other elements too

Answer (score 0):

Does below code help you a bit?

```
concat(//LMS.1/LMS.1.1/text(), //LMS.1/text())
```

Answer (score 0):

With the following select containing an or operand it is possible:

```
//LMS.1/LMS.1.1|//LMS.1[not(*)]
```

But it is not very beautiful, but works so far. Any other solutions?